# To erase or to wipe + computer information?

Tags: verbs

Which is correct? To erase computer information or to wipe computer information?

Comment: They mean different things.  Which one do you intend?

Comment: @Jim - In computer jargon they mean essentially the same.

Comment: "Erase" is probably more commonly used, but "wipe" is sometimes used to mean "completely eliminate all traces of".  And there are other terms that are sometimes used and might be more appropriate.  Probably this question is better suited for [Super User]( https://superuser.com) .

Comment: @HotLicks -  In the computer jargon I use, erase means a simple delete of all files but wipe means to sanitize in a way intended to prevent forensic recovery.

Comment: @Jim - Depends on the context.  If you want to completely eliminate all traces of the data, so that even the CIA couldn't retrieve it, you need to burn the device.

Comment: Most commonly, I hear the term "wipe" used when referring to hard drives, as "I'm going to wipe this hard drive and start over." I don't typically hear "wipe" applied to information directly, but to the device that contains the information. (This may be too subtle a distinction, but there it is.)

Comment: I don't think there's a generally agreed upon definition that would satisfy the entire spectrum of expertise in such technology. But if I were to say to a Judge "I erased the file" or "I wiped the file", I think the former could mean the normal actions of a user, and the latter would imply a bit more aggressive action, whatever the context. Bottom line: the words do imply different actions in some contexts to some users. Neither is "correct" in all situations.